# Neo4j return issue: How to map the properties of one node and one property from other node which connected into java object

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, cypher

I'm having some problems with mapping the properties which return from Neo4j to java.

I have a two connected nodes, Group (g) and Tenant (t), and the value which return is g,t.id.

In the java side, I have a group object but it's mapping only the group and not the tenantId.

In the group object, the type of tenantId is long, and if I change it to tenant object and return the full tenant with its relation, it map also the tenant, but I want that the group would contain only the id and not the whole tenant.

```
@NodeEntity(label = "Group")
public class GroupEntity extends AbstractBaseEntity {

    public static final String ENTITY_TYPE = "Group";

    @Property(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Property(name="description")
    private String description;

    @Relationship(type = "MEMBER_OF")
    private long tenantId;
}

//The query

@Query("MATCH (g:Group) where g.id = {groupId} " +
        "optional match (g)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(t:Tenant) " +
        "return g,t.id as tenantId")
Optional<GroupEntity> findById(Long groupId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work like that.

You map between entities.

But for a query you can return any shape of data and map it to a DTO that represents your needs.

e.g.

```
@Query("MATCH (g:Group) where g.id = {groupId} " +
        "optional match (g)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(t:Tenant) " +
        "return g, collect(t.id) as tenantIds")
Optional<GroupWithTenantIds> findById(Long groupId);

@QueryResult
static class GroupWithTenantIds {
  Group group;
  Set<Long> tenantIds;
}
```